# Javascript JSON strings with nul '\0'

Tags: javascript, json, null

Property-based testing uncovering a lot of bugs.  After fixing a bug with PostgreSQL, it ends up manifesting as a JavaScript bug.  This was tested in Chrome:

```
JSON.stringify("wee");      // "'wee'"
JSON.stringify("we\0e");    // ""we\u0000e""
JSON.parse("'we\u0000e'");  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0
JSON.parse('"we\u0000e"');  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 3
JSON.parse("\"we\u0000e\"");  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 3
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("we\u0000e")); // "we e" !!
```

The question is whether JSON should support '\0' in strings. PostgreSQL & C/C++ say no.  Others say sure. And others say maybe...

Either way, there is definitely some inconsistency between JSON.parse/stringify in Chrome JS.  Other json parsers have no problem with '\u0000'.

And I'm totally baffled by the last line!

Comment: `"'we\u0000e'"` is a Javascript string literal with a NUL character encoded as a backslash escape... What about `"'we\\u0000e'"`? Does that parse?

Comment: The third example is confusing, that would never be valid JSON (`'foo'`) regardless of null character support. Also, how characters are rendered and how they are represented in memory are two different things. Are you sure the code that renders out codepoints hasn't decided to render null as a space in your last example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON cannot contain NUL characters but it can contain the escape sequence `\u0000` to represent a NUL character. In JavaScript that would be represented as `'\\u0000'` (`'\u0000'` is just a string with length one; a single NUL character).

```js
console.log( JSON.parse('"we\\u0000e"') === "we\0e" );
```

Answer (score 5):

`JSON.stringify` with such strings results in a string with literal backslash characters:

```
JSON.stringify("we\0e");
```

results in a string containing

```
"we\u0000e"
```

(including the `"`s). This string does not contain an actual nul character - rather, it contains a `\` character, followed by `u`, followed by 4 zeros.

The problem with your first

```
JSON.parse("'we\u0000e'");
```

is that `JSON.parse` accepts only *double-quoted* strings, not single-quoted strings. (`` JSON.parse(`'foo'`) `` throws an error too)

The problem with the second

```
JSON.parse('"we\u0000e"');
```

is that the interpreter first de-escapes the string passed to `JSON.parse` to one containing an actual nul character, and `JSON.parse` doesn't understand such characters. The parsed string doesn't contain 11 characters, it only contains 6.

```js
console.log('"we\u0000e"');
console.log('"we\u0000e"'.length);
```

You need to indicate a *literal backslash*, followed by `u0000`, for the `JSON.parse` to work correctly:

```js
console.log('"we\\u0000e"'.length);
console.log(JSON.parse('"we\\u0000e"'));
```

If you chain together `JSON.parse` with `JSON.stringify`, it works just fine (things are less confusing when you don't have to escape everything manually):

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify("we\0e"));
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("we\0e")));
```

Comment: Ah the '\' needs to be escaped. Thank you.